# How handle i18n(with fallback) on MongoDB when translation is in another Collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, internationalization

Given these excerpt collections:

#### Translation Collection

```js
[
    {
      "_id": "id01_name",
      "text": "Item's Name"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id01_desc",
      "text": "Item's lore description"
    },
    {
      "_id": "sk_id",
      "text": "Item's skill description"
    },

  ]
```

#### Item Collection

```js
[
    {
      "_id": "id01",
      "name": "id01_name",
      "lore_description": "id01_desc",
      "skill": {
        "description": "sk_id01",
      }
    }
  ]
```

---

### Question:

Using only mongodb driver (NO Mongo ODM, like mongoose, iridium, etc), what is the best approach for (i18n) Internationalization (with fallback) on MongoDB when translation is in another Collection?

---

#### MongoDB's `aggregate` Approach

Currently, I'm using `aggregate` with `$lookup` to do these kind of queries.

```js
db.artifact.aggregate([
  { 
    $lookup: { // get the name's data from the english translation
      from: "text_en", 
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "name"
    },

  },
  {
    $unwind: "$name" //unwind because the lookup made name become an array with _id and text
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      name: "$name.text" //rewrite name (currently an obj) into the translation string
    }
  },

(...etc)
```

Problem is, I need these 3 steps on every single key I need to translate. On a big document, looks a bit too much, and every `$lookup` feels like the response time increases bit by bit.

This also doesn't have fallback cases, in case key is not available in said language, e.g., try `$lookup` on `id01_name` in the Spanish collection but the collection doesn't have it, so a fallback would be get from English collection.

Here a working example of the example above:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/umuPQYriFRe

---

#### Manual aggregation Approach

I also thought in doing in phases, that is,

- `item.find()` to get item data;
- `translation_english.find({ $in: [ (...listofkeys) ]})` to get all necessary english keys
- `translation_{otherlang}.find({ $in: [ (...listofkeys) ]})` to get all necessary other language keys
- manually transform the two translation arrays into two objects (with `cursor.forEach()`), merge with `Object.assign({},eng,otherlang)`
- handpicking each key and assigning to the item object

This method covers the fallback, but it's bloated/very verbose.

---

On a test with both attempts, lookup took 310ms and the manual took 500ms to complete, that for one lookup. But manual has fallback (aka queries 3 collections; `item, lang_en, lang_{foreign}`). If language key does not exist in foreign, it'll pick the en (it's assumed eng will never miss a key).
While lookup fails to return a document when the lookup on foreign lang fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the manual approach.

Currently you're using two queries to find the translation, but indeed it only should take one query if you merge the translation from multiple languages into a single document:

```
[
    {
      "_id": "id01_name",
      "en": "Item's Name",
      "fr": "fraf"
    },
    {
      "_id": "id01_desc",
      "en": "Item's lore description"
    },
    {
      "_id": "sk_id",
      "en": "Item's skill description",
      "jp": "jpjpj"
    },

  ]
```

Some considerations to improve the query speed:

- Use paging for items list returned. Even 100 items per page is easy to query. Not sure you need to support full collection retrieving but it's rare.
- Index the `translation` collection on single `en` field. You should fallback to `en` anyway so just need to query `where en = key`.
- Project the translation document with your language key, so there are just three fields returned: `en`, `__language__`, `_id`.
- Let the client do the rendering, they can choose the language field they need. If you really need a server pre-processor then the `for loop` over a page of 100 items does not hurt anyway.
- Consider to cache the translation into Redis, it's rarely updated anyway and you can take advantage of RAM speed.

Comment: I'll have both "list" and "detail" queries, where list will be all items (less than 200 entries but I will show all without pagination). I'll need to do the rendering on the server-side as it's part of a public API. Can you explain a bit further the "Index the translation collection on single en field" ?

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Suppose you want to get `fr` language. Currently you are query for `fr` first, then query for `en` for any missing key right? So you need two indices, one for `fr` and one for `en`. But you can do both at one: just query with `en` field, then if `fr` field exists, use it, if not, use `en` field. And you need only 1 index on `en` field

Comment: Got it. Not sure if I'll be able to do that, since the translation files are separated collections that every new update, I simply drop the collection and re-upload with `mongoimport`, and each collection has like 5MB of text. Mixing all languages into a single collection (there are 8 languages) and querying it entirely to then hand-pick the keys and apply will transmit too much data unnecessarily between servers (UI->API->Mongo->API->UI) since each of these are in a separate service (mLab or Atlas and 2x Heroku instances).

Comment: You always project only two fields to return: `en` and `fr` keys. No more different than have 8 or 80 languages